# How to update existing Rigify bone layers?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a rig generated from Rigify that also has a lot of manually added elements (drivers, etc.) added after the fact.
I'd like to add a new bone layer to the N-panel's "Rig Layers" tab, but I can't afford to regenerate the rig (I'll lose too much work).
Is there a way to add a new bone layer to the "Rig Layers" tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: custom rigify buttons]

The Rigify buttons in the N-panel are created by the *Rig UI Script*. You can define its name (*"rig_ui.py"*) in the *Object Data Properties* tab, in the *Rigify > Advanced* section when you have selected the *metarig* armature.

The *Re-Generate Rig* button creates this script taking into account the layers specified in *Rigify > Advanced > Layer Names*.

[image: extension of rig_ui.py]

Knowing this, you can **modify the *rig_ui.py* script without regenerating the rig**.

Switch to the *Scripting* workspace and select the *rig_ui.py* script from the dropdown menu. Now look for the *draw* function at the very end of the file (    `def draw(self, context):`). There you can add the lines for the custom layer buttons.

For example to create a button for bone layer 19 called "Robe" and layer 20 called "Cloak" add these three lines:

```
row = col.row()
row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=19, toggle=True, text='Robe')
row.prop(context.active_object.data, 'layers', index=20, toggle=True, text='Cloak')
```

Don't forget to run the script with the "play" button to see your custom Rigify buttons in the N-panel.

Comment: I completely forgot I asked this and eventually found this exact solution on my own, just with some more of a headache. Wish I had seen this answer sooner--it's perfect. Thanks so much!